# Force a page modal popup to hide with file download (ASP.NET C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, modalpopupextender

I need to use a modal popup extender object to allow a user to download a file from the server. The user clicks a button to show the popup, gives some input and presses a submit button on the panel embedded in the extender. The file is then generated and downloaded. All of that works perfectly now. The only problem I am having is getting the popup to hide again after the user clicks submit. I have a clear event set up that the code walks through, and if I comment out the download code it hides correctly. Here is my code:

ASP page:

```
<act:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeMailMerge" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlMailMerge" TargetControlID="btnGenerateMailMerge" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" />
<asp:Panel ID="pnlMailMerge"  CssClass="modalPopup" style="width:300px" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upMailMerge" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfIsSubmitted" Value="" runat="server" />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h3>What woud you like to do?</h3>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <dnr:CheckBox ID="chkFirstMailMergeGeneration" Field="" Name="First Mail Merge Generation" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="MailMergeCheckBoxChange" AutoPostback="true"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                First Mail Merge Generation
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <dnr:CheckBox ID="chkSubsequentGenerations" Field="" Name="Subsequent Generations" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="MailMergeCheckBoxChange" AutoPostback="true" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Subsequent Generations
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <dnr:Label ID="lblSubsequentMailMergeCount" For="txtSubsequentMailMergeCount" runat="server" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                &nbsp
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <dnr:Number ID="txtSubsequentMailMergeCount" DecimalDigits="0" Field="" Name="Generation Number " runat="server" Enabled="false" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                &nbsp
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnCountOfRowsToBeGenerated" Text="Generate Row Count" Name="Count of Rows to be generated" runat="server" Enabled="false" OnClick="BtnCountOfRowsToBeGenerated_Click" AutoPostback="true"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                &nbsp
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <dnr:Number ID="txtMailMergeRowCount" Field="" Name="Mail Merge Row Count" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                &nbsp
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitMailMerge" OnClick="BtnSubmitMailMerge_Click" Enabled="false" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                &nbsp
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnCancelMailMerge" OnClick="BtnCancelMailMerge_Click" Text="Cancel" runat="server" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnCountOfRowsToBeGenerated" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="chkFirstMailMergeGeneration" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="chkSubsequentGenerations" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmitMailMerge" />
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnCancelMailMerge" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```

C# behind:

```
protected void BtnSubmitMailMerge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.chkFirstMailMergeGeneration.Checked || this.chkSubsequentGenerations.Checked)
        {
            MailMergeGenerator gen = new MailMergeGenerator();
            if (this.chkFirstMailMergeGeneration.Checked)
            {
                // File download method
                gen.DownloadMailMerge(0, this.Context);
            }
            else if (this.chkSubsequentGenerations.Checked)
            {
                // File download method
                gen.DownloadMailMerge((int)this.txtSubsequentMailMergeCount.Value, this.Context);
            }
            this.BtnCancelMailMerge_Click(null, null);
        }
    }

public void DownloadMailMerge(int timesGenerated, HttpContext context)
    {
        System.Linq.IQueryable<MailMergeReport> report = this.GetMailMergeReport(timesGenerated);

        // export report
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo("/MailMerge.xlsx");
        ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(file);

        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"MailMerge.xlsx\"");//cause Save As prompt
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";//set the document MIME type
        context.Response.Expires = -1;
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(excelPackage.GetAsByteArray());
        context.Response.Flush();
        context.Response.Close();
    }
```

Any help anyone could give me on this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in three steps:

1. Download and reference jquery.cookie.js to your porject.
2. Create cookie response to tell Javascript that the creation of file is done.
3. Create Javascript that can notify the cookie.

In your case, you can do like these:

Make your "btnSubmitMailMerge" button "ClientIDMode" to be "static" (need to trigger click event by javascript)

Add:

```
context.Response.AppendCookie(new HttpCookie("download_flag", "trans_success"));
```

Within Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
          $('#btnSubmitMailMerge').on('click', function () {
              var fileDownloadCheckTimer;
                 ModalShow();//show your modal here
                 fileDownloadCheckTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
                 var cookieValue = $.cookie('download_flag');
                console.log(cookieValue + "---> Cookie Value;");
                if (cookieValue == "trans_success")
                    finishDownload();
            }, 1000);//Check if receive cookie from server by second

            function finishDownload() {
                ModalHide();//hide your modal.
                console.log("finish");
                $.cookie("download_flag", null, { path: '/' });//clear cookie

                window.clearInterval(fileDownloadCheckTimer);  //clear timer
            }
        });
    });
```